# Horizontal scroll controls volume?

Tags: windows, autohotkey, scrolling

Does someone know how I can use autohotkey to replace the horizontal screen function of my gaming mouse with a volume up and down feature? Most people in these forums are trying to enable horizontal scrolling and that is not what I am doing. I want to use the scroll wheel to change volume. Thanks for any help

Comment: @andrewdotnich honestly, I doubt a single person would read through all of that, ever

Comment: @user1306322: ok, tl;dr:

"So next time you’re considering asking a question, you’d better be ready with a convincing answer when you’re asked “What have you tried?”

If your answer amounts to “not a lot”, take my word for it: the next question you get back will be “then why should I help you?”"

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
WheelLeft::{Volume_Up}
WheelRight::{Volume_Up}
```

This link may also be of help:

http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/24771-mouse-buttons-as-hotkey/#entry160646